# how to show activity indicator in iphone application while uploading data

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

I am uploading data to server i want that when i click upload button then activity indicator should start and stop after the data is uploaded.

This is how i am uploading data but activity indicator not working.

```
       -(IBAction)startSyncButtonAction{

        [self startActivity];   
    CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


   for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

   Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


    int mycount=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];
    NSLog(@"My Array count is %d",mycount);


    NSString*device_Id=coffeeObj.device_Id;
    NSString*R1=coffeeObj.R1;
    NSString*R2=coffeeObj.R2;
    NSString*R3=coffeeObj.R3;
    NSString*R4=coffeeObj.R4;
    NSString*R5=coffeeObj.R5;
    NSString*R6=coffeeObj.R6;
    NSString*R7=coffeeObj.R7;
    NSString*R8=coffeeObj.R8;
        NSString*R9=coffeeObj.R9;
    NSString*R10=coffeeObj.R10;
    NSString*R11=coffeeObj.R11;
    NSString*R12=coffeeObj.R12;
    NSString*R13=coffeeObj.R13;
    NSString*R14=coffeeObj.R14;     

        NSString*update_date_time=coffeeObj.update_date_time;

         NSString*teritory1=coffeeObj.teritory;

         int mycount1=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

         NSLog(@"My Array After delete is %d",mycount1);
            NSLog(@"device_Id%@",device_Id);
    NSLog(@"R1%@",R1);
    NSLog(@"R2%@",R2);
    NSLog(@"R3%@",R3);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R4);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R5);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R6);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R7);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R8);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R9);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R10);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R11);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R12);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R13);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R14);

     NSLog(@"update_date_time%@",update_date_time);

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"device_Id=%@&R1=%@&R2=%@&R3=%@&R4=%@&R5=%@&R6=%@&R7=%@&R8=%@&R9=%@&R10=%@&R11=%@&R12=%@&R13=%@&R14=%@&update_date_time=%@&teritory1=%@",device_Id,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,update_date_time,teritory1];



      NSLog(post);
      NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/pfizersurvey/SyncSurveySTD.php"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);

       }


        for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


     [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];

    }

    }

     -(void)startActivity:(id)sender
  {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    activityImageView.hidden=NO;
    activityView.hidden=NO;

    [activityView startAnimating];

     [pool release];
    }
```

Comment: Where have you written the code to add the activity indicator on view?

Comment: @Rushi i have written that also but forget to add over here

Comment: Can you put that code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code but I am giving example you should modify it & use according to your need:

```
 alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];

                UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

                indicator.center = CGPointMake(150, 100);
                [indicator startAnimating];
                [alert addSubview:indicator];
```

Use this line to dismiss indicator:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Try. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For better user experience i will recommend you to use [`UIProgressHUD`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIProgressHUD)

```
UIProgressHUD* hud = [[UIProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[hud setText:@"Loading, please wait."];
[hud showInView:someView];
... 
[hud done];
...
[hud hide];
...
[hud release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that activityView is not nil?? I don't see anywhere you set it to anything. Also, even it were not nil, have you added it to a view? activityView is just a regular UIView, it won't automatically appear in UIWindows.